# Javascript Equating Variable .value

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the code I'm working from: http://jsfiddle.net/9B84H/26/

```
function autosuggest() {
var input = document.getElementById('location');
    var options = {types: [],};
    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
}

function getLatLng() {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById('location').value;
    geocoder.geocode({
        'address': address
    }, function (results, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
            $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
        } else {
            alert("Geocode failed: " + status);
        }
    });
}
```

There are two variables which are pretty much the same​:

```
var address = document.getElementById('location').value;
var input = document.getElementById('location');
```

Is there any opportunity to combine this into one line as a global variable?

Comment: `var input=$('#location'), adress=input.val();`, on the other hand those are two different functions, and globals usually is'nt the solution, so just getting the element once more is'nt that bad.

Comment: Also note that the Geocoding API from Google may only be used in conjunction with a Google map!

Answer (score 0):

You could use your anonymous self invoking function or just use the dom-ready method in jQuery to wrap your code (dom-ready seems like a better idea if you don´t put your JS code at the bottom of the page).

I did an example removing the onclick, onfocus attribute on your input and put them in the javascript section: http://jsfiddle.net/9B84H/27/

```
$(function() {
    var location = document.getElementById('location');
    var getLatLng = function() {
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        var address = location.value;
        geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        }, function (results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                alert("Geocode success");
            } else {
                alert("Geocode failed: " + status);
            }
        });
    };
    var autosuggest = function() {
        var options = {types: []};
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(location, options);
    };
    $("#location").on("focus", autosuggest);
    $(":button[name='Geocode']").on("click", getLatLng);
});
```

you now have a local variable named `location` that reference the #location element in your document.

Comment: Is there a benefit of this way over self invoking? Also for some reason the geocoding in your example doesnt work.

Comment: remove `:button` and change it to `[value='Geocode']` not the name, was way tired when I wrote this. The big benefit with this is that id doesn't really matter where you put the code, it will run as soon as we can read the DOM